# DateTime remove saturday and sunday

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, luxon

I am creating a todo where the default date should be set to + 3 days but only weekdays. I'm using vue so think a computed of some sort should work?

`DateTime.utc().plus({ days: 3 }).toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),`

So how can I exclude Saturday and Sunday here? I've tried googling but haven't been able to find a solution..

Comment: Seen as your using Luxon, this might be useful, -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/luxon-business-days

Comment: Ah thank you! But I don't know if I can install more packages. Do you have a suggestion of how to do it without a new package? :D

Answer (score 1):

the best solution is to use the package luxon-business-day

but if you don't want to add anything
you can :

- calculate date of next saturday
- see if you can add expecting number of day
- if not, add difference to day to add

```js
const dayToAdd = 3;
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

var nextSaturday = DateTime.utc().startOf('week').plus({ week: 1 }).minus({days: 2});
var dayDifference = nextSaturday.diff(DateTime.utc(), ["days"]).toObject().days;


var addAfterWeekend = 0;
if (dayDifference < dayToAdd) {
  addAfterWeekend = dayToAdd - dayDifference;
}

var date = DateTime.utc().plus({ days: dayToAdd + addAfterWeekend });

console.log(date.toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.21.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually just solved it before with this:

```export const onlyWeekdays = DateTime.utc().startOf('week').endOf('week').minus({ days: 2 })

export const postponeThreeDays = onlyWeekdays
    .plus({ days: 3 })
    .startOf('day')
    .plus({ hours: 9 })
    .toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')```